# Usage of "than"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, parts-of-speech, conjunctions

> Buying on margin means borrowing money from a broker to buy more securities **than** can be purchased with one's own money alone.

1. I was wondering if *than* in the above example is a conjunction or preposition?
2. Is there some word left out in the part after *than*? If yes, is the
   complete sentence

   > Buying on margin means borrowing money from a broker to buy more
   >   securities than **what** can be purchased with one's own money
   >   alone.

   **Added:** "can be purchased", the part after "than", is not a complete sentence because of lacking the subject, compared to a more usual example "He is taller than I am".
3. Can somebody explain a little more about the usage of *than* in
   examples like this? I would like to understand how the sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing missing. Stripping the sentence down to the construction in question, we get ‘more securities than can be purchased.’ This is on the same pattern as, say, ‘more food than can be eaten’, and is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Thanks! But "can be purchased", the part after "than", is not a complete sentence because of lacking the subject, compared to a more usual example "He is taller than I am".

Comment: The subject is implicit. Fully expanded the sentence would read ‘Buying on margin means borrowing money from a broker to buy more securities than those securities which can be purchased with one's own money alone.’

Comment: Thanks! (1) In this expansion, is "than" a prep or conj? (2) It looks like a prep, since what follows "than" is a noun not a sentence. In this sense, can I replace "those securities which" by "what"? (3) If I want to use "than" as a conj, can I say "Buying on margin means borrowing money from a broker to buy more securities than those securities can be purchased with one's own money alone." because the part after "than" now is a complete sentence.

Comment: @Tim: Sorry not to have replied sooner, but I’ve only just seen your comment. ‘Than’ here is a subordinating conjunction (often termed simply a subordinator) joining the two clauses ‘Buying . . . securities’ and ‘can . . . alone.’ If you replace ‘those securities which’ by ‘what’, you leave it unclear as to what it is being referred to. If you wanted to use the sentence in (3), you’d have to insert ‘that’ (or ‘which’) between ‘securities’ and ‘can’.